# Crashes on Huawei Android 7-10

Tags: java, android, crash-dumps, android-vitals

I have in Android vitals almost the same type of crashes. All crashes are from Huawei devices.
 Probably relates with: [link](https://github.com/bumptech/glide/issues/4116), because I am using Glide too.
Could you help me, what can cause such an error? I know, that's something with bitmap, but I do not know what.
Do you have similar experience?
Thank you.

This is from Android 9:

```
  #00  pc 0000000000022988  /system/lib64/libc.so (abort+116)
  #01  pc 0000000000048160  /system/lib64/libc.so (__fortify_fatal(char const*, ...)+120)
  #02  pc 0000000000048630  /system/lib64/libc.so (__read_chk+68)
  #03  pc 0000000000002550  /system/lib64/libdrmbitmap.huawei.so (android::SkDrmFileStream::isDrmFile(int)+316)
  #04  pc 0000000000001e44  /system/lib64/libdrmbitmap.huawei.so (nativeDecodeFileDescriptorEx(_JNIEnv*, _jobject*, _jobject*, _jobject*, _jobject*)+304)
  #05  pc 000000000041de34  /system/framework/arm64/boot-framework.oat (offset 0x415000) (android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeFileDescriptor [DEDUPED]+228)
  #06  pc 00000000008a6010  /system/framework/arm64/boot-framework.oat (offset 0x415000) (android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeFileDescriptor+512)
  #07  pc 00000000003704a4  /data/app/com.example.testApp-DWBKy-ULUo0FnOUvo0xWag==/oat/arm64/base.odex (offset 0x159000) (sj$b.a+132)
  #08  pc 000000000029c1b0  /data/app/com.example.testApp-DWBKy-ULUo0FnOUvo0xWag==/oat/arm64/base.odex (offset 0x159000) (mj.a+336)
  #09  pc 000000000029d654  /data/app/com.example.testApp-DWBKy-ULUo0FnOUvo0xWag==/oat/arm64/base.odex (offset 0x159000) (mj.b+68)
  #10  pc 000000000029d91c  /data/app/com.example.testApp-DWBKy-ULUo0FnOUvo0xWag==/oat/arm64/base.odex (offset 0x159000) (mj.a+140)
  #11  pc 000000000029ee1c  /data/app/com.example.testApp-DWBKy-ULUo0FnOUvo0xWag==/oat/arm64/base.odex (offset 0x159000) (mj.a+1132)
  #12  pc 0000000000376c18  /data/app/com.example.testApp-DWBKy-ULUo0FnOUvo0xWag==/oat/arm64/base.odex (offset 0x159000) (vj.a+472)
  #13  pc 000000000026d0a0  /data/app/com.example.testApp-DWBKy-ULUo0FnOUvo0xWag==/oat/arm64/base.odex (offset 0x159000) (dg.a+464)
  #14  pc 000000000026cca0  /data/app/com.example.testApp-DWBKy-ULUo0FnOUvo0xWag==/oat/arm64/base.odex (offset 0x159000) (dg.a+256)
  #15  pc 000000000026ce3c  /data/app/com.example.testApp-DWBKy-ULUo0FnOUvo0xWag==/oat/arm64/base.odex (offset 0x159000) (dg.a+60)
  #16  pc 00000000002a1770  /data/app/com.example.testApp-DWBKy-ULUo0FnOUvo0xWag==/oat/arm64/base.odex (offset 0x159000) (ng.a+320)
  #17  pc 00000000002a14dc  /data/app/com.example.testApp-DWBKy-ULUo0FnOUvo0xWag==/oat/arm64/base.odex (offset 0x159000) (ng.a+268)
  #18  pc 00000000002e3474  /data/app/com.example.testApp-DWBKy-ULUo0FnOUvo0xWag==/oat/arm64/base.odex (offset 0x159000) (cg.a+276)
  #19  pc 00000000002e3058  /data/app/com.example.testApp-DWBKy-ULUo0FnOUvo0xWag==/oat/arm64/base.odex (offset 0x159000) (cg.a+392)
  #20  pc 00000000002e4df8  /data/app/com.example.testApp-DWBKy-ULUo0FnOUvo0xWag==/oat/arm64/base.odex (offset 0x159000) (cg.e+504)
  #21  pc 00000000002e457c  /data/app/com.example.testApp-DWBKy-ULUo0FnOUvo0xWag==/oat/arm64/base.odex (offset 0x159000) (cg.a+396)
  #22  pc 000000000037197c  /data/app/com.example.testApp-DWBKy-ULUo0FnOUvo0xWag==/oat/arm64/base.odex (offset 0x159000) (tg.a+348)
  #23  pc 00000000003717dc  /data/app/com.example.testApp-DWBKy-ULUo0FnOUvo0xWag==/oat/arm64/base.odex (offset 0x159000) (tg$a.a+140)
  #24  pc 0000000000361f64  /data/app/com.example.testApp-DWBKy-ULUo0FnOUvo0xWag==/oat/arm64/base.odex (offset 0x159000) (mf.a+324)
  #25  pc 0000000000371d20  /data/app/com.example.testApp-DWBKy-ULUo0FnOUvo0xWag==/oat/arm64/base.odex (offset 0x159000) (tg.a+864)
  #26  pc 00000000002e55fc  /data/app/com.example.testApp-DWBKy-ULUo0FnOUvo0xWag==/oat/arm64/base.odex (offset 0x159000) (cg.k+236)
  #27  pc 00000000002e4ec8  /data/app/com.example.testApp-DWBKy-ULUo0FnOUvo0xWag==/oat/arm64/base.odex (offset 0x159000) (cg.e+712)
  #28  pc 00000000002e457c  /data/app/com.example.testApp-DWBKy-ULUo0FnOUvo0xWag==/oat/arm64/base.odex (offset 0x159000) (cg.a+396)
  #29  pc 000000000037197c  /data/app/com.example.testApp-DWBKy-ULUo0FnOUvo0xWag==/oat/arm64/base.odex (offset 0x159000) (tg.a+348)
  #30  pc 00000000003717dc  /data/app/com.example.testApp-DWBKy-ULUo0FnOUvo0xWag==/oat/arm64/base.odex (offset 0x159000) (tg$a.a+140)
  #31  pc 0000000000361f64  /data/app/com.example.testApp-DWBKy-ULUo0FnOUvo0xWag==/oat/arm64/base.odex (offset 0x159000) (mf.a+324)
  #32  pc 0000000000371d20  /data/app/com.example.testApp-DWBKy-ULUo0FnOUvo0xWag==/oat/arm64/base.odex (offset 0x159000) (tg.a+864)
  #33  pc 00000000002e55fc  /data/app/com.example.testApp-DWBKy-ULUo0FnOUvo0xWag==/oat/arm64/base.odex (offset 0x159000) (cg.k+236)
  #34  pc 00000000002e5b9c  /data/app/com.example.testApp-DWBKy-ULUo0FnOUvo0xWag==/oat/arm64/base.odex (offset 0x159000) (cg.l+380)
  #35  pc 00000000002e6054  /data/app/com.example.testApp-DWBKy-ULUo0FnOUvo0xWag==/oat/arm64/base.odex (offset 0x159000) (cg.run+180)
  #36  pc 000000000046fab4  /system/framework/arm64/boot.oat (offset 0x13b000) (java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.processTask+1156)
  #37  pc 0000000000471634  /system/framework/arm64/boot.oat (offset 0x13b000) (java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker+84)
  #38  pc 000000000046d8b0  /system/framework/arm64/boot.oat (offset 0x13b000) (java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run+64)
  #39  pc 00000000002c1038  /system/framework/arm64/boot.oat (offset 0x13b000) (java.lang.Thread.run+72)
  #40  pc 00000000002b7be4  /data/app/com.example.testApp-DWBKy-ULUo0FnOUvo0xWag==/oat/arm64/base.odex (offset 0x159000) (sh$b$a.run+180)
  #41  pc 0000000000571d88  /system/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_stub+584)
  #42  pc 00000000000d4d2c  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::ArtMethod::Invoke(art::Thread*, unsigned int*, unsigned int, art::JValue*, char const*)+200)
  #43  pc 0000000000475d3c  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::(anonymous namespace)::InvokeWithArgArray(art::ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnable const&, art::ArtMethod*, art::(anonymous namespace)::ArgArray*, art::JValue*, char const*)+104)
  #44  pc 0000000000476df8  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::InvokeVirtualOrInterfaceWithJValues(art::ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnable const&, _jobject*, _jmethodID*, jvalue*)+424)
  #45  pc 00000000004a23ec  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::Thread::CreateCallback(void*)+1120)
  #46  pc 0000000000083588  /system/lib64/libc.so (__pthread_start(void*)+36)
  #47  pc 00000000000241dc  /system/lib64/libc.so (__start_thread+68)
```

This is from Android 7.0:

```
  #00  pc 000000000006bc40  /system/lib64/libc.so (tgkill+8)
  #01  pc 00000000000690dc  /system/lib64/libc.so (pthread_kill+64)
  #02  pc 0000000000023e68  /system/lib64/libc.so (raise+24)
  #03  pc 000000000001c8ec  /system/lib64/libc.so (abort+52)
  #04  pc 0000000000020e74  /system/lib64/libc.so (__libc_fatal+104)
  #05  pc 0000000000020e08  /system/lib64/libc.so (__fortify_chk_fail+52)
  #06  pc 0000000000074620  /system/lib64/libc.so (__read_chk+40)
  #07  pc 0000000000002658  /system/lib64/libdrmbitmap.huawei.so (android::SkDrmFileStream::isDrmFile(int)+312)
  #08  pc 0000000000001f1c  /system/lib64/libdrmbitmap.huawei.so
  #09  pc 0000000075c88fb0  /data/dalvik-cache/arm64/system@framework@boot-framework.oat (offset 0x1924000)
```

Comment: encounter the same issue on Huawei P30 Android 10.

It happened sometimes and once happened, it will stuck there.

Comment: My customers have the same issue. I do not have device to reproduce this bug

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a bug in Glide 4.11
See https://github.com/bumptech/glide/issues/4165

Running well with previous versions (4.10.0). Tested.